# Transaction log of DDL

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, acid

How does storage engines such as InnoDB achieve ACID for DDL statement. In a DDL statement such as `CREATE TABLE ...`, some intermediate files/directories have to be created and if any operation fail unexpectedly those files have to be cleaned up. So the storage engine has to remember which files/directories they had created and clean up (the clean up process can also fail, though...). I suppose they use journaling (Write Ahead Logging) for that. But can anyone provide a simple self-contained protocol for that?

Comment: They don't. "Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored routines." [Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html) Other dbms support DDL in transactions, though.

Comment: Before MySQL 8.0, there was essentially no ACID for DDL statements.  8.0's "Data Dictionary" changes that--drastically.